# Operator not working in switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

This is my code but after typing input it is giving statement of default every time. Please Help.I am a beginner to C.
It is not giving result.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char op;
    printf ("Enter first number: ");
    scanf ("%d", & a );
    printf ("Enter second number: ");
    scanf ("%d", & b );
    printf ("Enter the operator: ");
    scanf ("%s", op );
    switch(op)
    {
         case '+' : 
                       printf("Sum is %d", a+b );
         break;
         case '-' : 
                       printf("Difference is %d", a-b );
         break;
         case '*' : 
                       printf("Product is %d", a*b );
         break;
         case '/' : 
                       printf("Quotient is %d", a/b );
         break;
         default : 
                       printf("Wrong operator used!");
         break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `scanf (" %c", &op );`, not `scanf ("%s", op );`.

Comment: Does your even compile without warnings? `scanf ("%s", op );` is incorrect because you are passing a `char` when scanf expects a `char*`. Perhaps you meant `scanf (" %c", &op );`.

Comment: Not working...returning 0 as value....can't even enter operator now

Comment: Please read carefully - every comment, and the answer, has a space before `%c`. Please see [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Comment: This is the point where you should start using a debugger to step through your program. That should always be the very first action to identify problems. Check your variables and where your program flow is.

Comment: thnx Weather Vane and everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
scanf ("%s", op );
```

is undefined behavior, `op` is `char` but `%s` requires `char *` (and more than a single `char` of space, if you expect to actually store a string there which you don't need).

You meant:

```
scanf(" %c", &op); // Note the space before '%', this matters.
```

also always check the return values, I/O can fail.

Comment: Not working....by using scanf("%c",&op);    it is not even asking me for input for operators...I enter two number then press "enter" and it returns 0

Comment: I triend scanf("%c",op);.....but not working...it shows text.exe stopped working at the time when I had to enter operator

Comment: @SameerYadav try copy-pasting the exact code into your program.

Comment: thnx unwind...I wrote "%c" and not " %c"...thnx for helping

Comment: @SameerYadav please show your thanks by "accepting" this answer. There is a check box.